Does Goldbach's Conjecture imply a stronger statement about prime pair distributions?
The discussion on F. Brunault's question  and extensive calculations suggest:
$$ \qquad f_{n+1} < 4p_n \quad\text{for}\quad n > 0$$
where $f_n$ is the Frobenius number of the numerical semigroup generated by the primes greater or equal to the $n-$th prime $p_n$. This conjecture together with Goldbachs conjecture G that every even number x greater than 2 is the sum of two primes suggests the following version of Goldbach's Conjecture G'
Every even number $x > 2$ is the sum $x = p + q$ of primes $p \leq q$ with the property
$x/4 < p ≤ x/2$
If $x = 2k$ and $k$ is not prime, this obviously results in
$$
x/4 \lt p \lt x/2 \lt q \lt 3x/4.\label{1}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
Unfortunately, the latter does not hold for the primes $k = 2, 3, 7, 11, 19,$ and $43$.
However, extensive calculations suggest that:
(G'') Every even number $x$, except for $2, 4, 6, 14, 22, 38,$ and $86$, has a representation $x = p + q$ as the sum of two primes with the property \eqref{1}.
Question:
Does Goldbach's Conjecture G imply statement G''?
In this context, it should also be mentioned that Schinzel already showed in 1959 Démonstration d'une conséquence de l'hypothèse de Goldbach that every integer n > 17 is the sum of three distinct prime numbers, and consequently, every even number x > 6 is the sum of two distinct prime numbers
In this context, it should also be mentioned that Schinzel already showed in 1959 Démonstration d'une conséquence de l'hypothèse de Goldbach, that the Goldbach conjecture implies, that every integer $n>17$ is the sum of three distinct prime numbers, in particular, the Goldbach conjecture implies, that every even number $x>6$ is the sum of two distinct prime numbers.
This is mentioned in here and in "The New Book of Prime Number Records" by Ribenboim (page 296)
Edit: made some clarifications, the statement about Schinzels result was wrong as stated (as pointed out by GH)
Edit: sorry for all the confusion, this question should be deleted. I quoted the wrong paper - the result is proved in: Andrzej Schinzel,   Sur une conséquence de l'hypothèse de Goldbach, Bulgar. Akad. Nauk. Izv. 4 (1959), 35-38.


Schinzel clearly did not show in 1959 that "every even number $x>6$ is the sum of two distinct prime numbers" as this is a strengthening of the Goldbach conjecture. BTW I believe that the standard Hardy-Littlewood heuristics implying the Goldbach conjecture can be modified to show that the two primes in the decomposition $x=p+q$ can be taken to be nearly equal. This is certainly known for the ternary Goldbach decompositions $x=p+q+r$. Finally, I am fairly certain that it is not known that G implies G''.

Perhaps Schinzel proved those results, conditional on the Goldbach Conjecture? That would accord with the title of the paper.

But then the conclusion "...and consequently, every even number $x>6$ is the sum of two distinct prime numbers" makes no sense at all. And looking at the paper quoted, I see no evidence of either assertion being proved.

If you want the question deleted, you can delete it.

As there is already an answer, I will not delete the question.

The answer to your question is yes. Goldbach's conjecture is equivalent to saying that every integer larger than $1$ admits a primality radius, that is, a non negative integer $r$ such that both $n-r$ and $n+r$ are prime. Now the comments below the answer to Does $0<k<n$ imply $p_{n+k}<\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k p_{n}$ for large enough $n$? show that, provided $n$ is a large enough composite integer, $r_{0}(n):=\inf\{r\geq 0\mid (n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}<\frac{n}{2}$, from which your claim follows.
